# How to change case of back references?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to modify a back reference in PowerShell but am having no luck :(

This is my example:

```
"456,Jane Doe" -replace '^(\d{3}),(.*)$',"| $(`"`$2`".ToUpper()) | `$1 |"
```

If I run it I get this:

| Jane Doe | 456 |

But I'm really expecting this:

| JANE DOE | 456 |

If I run the following (the same as above but without the '()' on the call to ToUpper):

```
"456,Jane Doe" -replace '^(\d{3}),(.*)$',"| $(`"`$2`".ToUpper) | `$1 |"
```

I get this:

```
| string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) | 456 |
```

So it would appear that PowerShell knows that the back reference '$2' is a string but why can't I get PowerShell to convert it to upper case?

Terry

Comment: Note that `"$2"` is of course always a string since it's enclosed in quotation marks. It's just that the string is empty unless you assigned a value to `$2` somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
[Regex]::Replace('456,Jane Doe',
    '^(\d{3}),(.*)$',
    {
        param($m)
        '| ' + $m.Groups[2].Value.ToUpper() + ' | ' + $m.Groups[1].Value + ' |'
    }
)
```

Not very pretty, I admit. And you sadly cannot use script blocks as replacement in the `-replace` operator.

Comment: That's mostly because there is no native support for callbacks in the `-replace` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain what is happening, in `` "| $(`"`$2`".ToUpper()) | `$1 |" `` PowerShell is evaluating the highlighted subexpression *before* passing the string to the `-replace` operator, rather than after the replace operation has occurred.

In other words, [`ToUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper.aspx) is called on the string value `$2`, resulting in `| $2 | $1 |` being used for the replace operation. You can see this by including a letter in the subexpression string, for example:

```powershell
"456,Jane Doe" -replace '^(\d{3}),(.*)$',"| $(`"zz `$2`".ToUpper()) | `$1 |"
```

This has an effective replace string of `| ZZ $2 | $1 |`, giving `| ZZ Jane Doe | 456 |` as the result.

Similarly, the second version omitting parenthesis, `` "| $(`"`$2`".ToUpper) | `$1 |" ``, is evaluated as `"some string".ToUpper`, which puts the array of overload definitions for the `ToUpper` method on [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) in the replace string.

To keep the replace operation as a one-liner, [Joey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6818904/2495) using [the `MatchEvaluator` overload to `Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx) works well. Or you might do the string formatting yourself based on the results of a `-match`:

```powershell
if( '456,Jane Doe' -match '^(\d{3}),(.*)$' ) {
  '| {0} | {1} |' -f $matches[2].ToUpper(),$matches[1]
}
```

If this needs to be replaced in the context of a larger string, you can always do a literal replace to get the final result:

```
PS> $r = '| {0} | {1} |' -f $matches[2].ToUpper(),$matches[1]
PS> 'A longer string with 456,Jane Doe in it.'.Replace( $matches[0], $r )
A longer string with | JANE DOE | 456 | in it.
```