# Powershell Replace with a Lookup Variable

Tags: function, powershell, replace

I've tried this in powershell with -replace and with [RegEx]::replace.  same issue.  I want to use the value in a capture group to retrieve its value from a lookup duing the replace on a string.

assuming t is a a valid hash table of key/value where one key is 'gif'.

```
[RegEx]::Replace($_, "((/aaa)?/bbb[^']+).(jpg|png|bmp|gif)", "--`$1--`$2--`$3--$($t.Item('`$3'))++++`$1-UUUUU.`$3")
```

Needless to say, i've been unsuccessful with getting the hash lookup to work in this substitution.

Comment: What are you talking about? Give some example and code that you actually used.

Comment: Ok, code wasn't formatted properly and disappeared. But still give example what you want. Question is very vague.

Comment: see also: [How to change case of back references?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6818809)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you can use a MatchEvaluator like so:

```
$evaluator ={
$t = @{ "jpg"="This is a jpeg image";
        "gif"="This is a gif image"}
$group1 = $args[0].groups[1]
$t["$group1"]
}

[RegEx]::Replace("test.gif","^.*\.(jpg|gif)", $evaluator,[Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::none)
```